# nextsibiling doesn't work

Tags: javascript

this is a sample code of what I am doing. unfortunately the alert(nextElem.value) returns "undefined" when I click the second checkbox to get the href of the link after it. do you have any idea how to fix it?

```
   <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Checkbox Inspector</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function validate()
{
    for (i = 0; i <(document.f1.checkThis.length) ; i++) {
        if (document.f1.checkThis[i].checked) {
            var elem = document.f1.checkThis[i];
            var nextElem = elem.nextSibling; 
            alert(nextElem.href);
            }
        }
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM name="f1">
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkThis" value="http://www.google.com" onClick="validate()">Check here<BR>
<a href="http://www.google.com">click here</a>    
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to validate? Assuming you correctly access the checkbox's sibling checkbox (which, as has been shown, you're not actually doing), checking its value based on the checked state of the previous checkbox doesn't make much sense. Do you want to check the value of the checked checkbox? State your goal, and we can probably suggest a more appropriate approach.

Comment: can you please see editted question. I need to know the href of the link that is after the selected checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

**Get the link's href with jQuery**

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/H9Raz/ :

```
$('form input:checkbox').click(function () {
 alert($(this).nextAll('a').attr("href"));
});
```

Because of the BRs we need the nextAll, surprisingly since I was using the [next selector](http://api.jquery.com/next/#next-selector) with an "a"

See here why it did not work: [Cleanest way to get the next sibling in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237673/cleanest-way-to-get-a-sibling-in-jquery/6237884#6237884)

---

**Get the link's href with forms access and usage of ID - no jQuery**

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fKE3v/

```js
window.onload=function() {
  var chks = document.getElementsByName('checkThis');
    for (var i=0;i<chks.length;i++) {
        chks[i].onclick=function() {
            var id = this.id;
            var linkId="link_"+id.split("_")[1]
            alert(document.getElementById(linkId).href)
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkThis" id="chk_1" value="http://www.google.com" />Check here<br/>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" id="link_1">click here</a><br>   
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkThis" id="chk_2" value="http://www.bing.com" />Check here<br/>
    <a href="http://www.bing.com" id="link_2">click here</a>       
  </div>
</form>
```

---

**Forms access to get the next checkbox**

```html
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkThis" value="http://www.google.com" onClick="validate(this.form)">Check here<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkThis"  onClick="validate(this.form)">Check here2<BR>
```

```js
function validate(theForm) {
    var chk = theForm.checkThis
    for (i = 0; i <chk.length) ; i++) {
        if (chk[i].checked) {
            var nextElem = chk[i+1]; 
            if (nextElem) alert(nextElem.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please see editted question. I need to know the href of the link that is after the selected checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `nextElem` is the text node immediately after your checkbox, not the next checkbox; text nodes don't have `value` attributes. For example, try this:

```
function validate() {
    for (i = 0; i < (document.f1.checkThis.length); i++) {
        if (document.f1.checkThis[i].checked) {
            var elem = document.f1.checkThis[i];
            var nextElem = elem.nextSibling;
            alert(nextElem);
            alert(nextElem.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Or, for your convenience:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/sUzBL/1/

Comment: @nasi: Cool, that's the right approach and less dependent on your DOM structure. You might want to accept his answer by clicking on the checkbox.

Comment: can you please see editted question. I need to know the href of the link that is after the selected checkbox.

Comment: @nasi: That's a whole new question, not a simple edit. Here's a hint `elem.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling` but you really want to use a loop instead.

Comment: I am sorry for that. but even by using your suggestion I can't get the href. alert(elem.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.href) returns "undefined"

Comment: @nasi: One last hint: `document.f1.checkThis` isn't an array anymore.

Comment: @mu is too short: I don't get what you mean by "document.f1.checkThis isn't an array anymore"! it is an array and by "alert(i)", I can get the correct index of a selected checkbox.

Comment: @nasi: Your updated example only has one `checkThis` checkbox so `document.f1.checkThis` should be just that element rather than an array of checkboxes.