# Cleanest way to get the next sibling in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/H9Raz/

After quite some tests with next('a') and such, I finally found one that worked.
I just wonder why next('a') did not, or closest or similar. Are there cleaner ways to get at the href of the link after the checkbox I click?

```
$('form input:checkbox').click(function () {
 alert($(this).nextAll('a').attr("href"));
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkThis" value="http://www.google.com" />Check here<br/>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">click here</a><br>   
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkThis" value="http://www.bing.com" />Check here<br/>
    <a href="http://www.bing.com">click here</a>       
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't use `next()` because the `<br>` element is in the way. So, `nextAll()` is indeed the best solution as far as I can tell.

Comment: This of course also works. But is hackier and requires the <br> tag. http://jsfiddle.net/AFFr3/

Comment: @mplungjan You can ditch the BR elements by declaring the ANCHOR's or INPUT's (or both) to be block-level elements (of course, only locally, not for the entire page). That would be my recommendation... **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/H9Raz/4/

Comment: @Fred @Arend, but I used [next("a")](http://api.jquery.com/next/#next-selector) - should ignore the br I would think!

Comment: @Andy: You added a lang:html thingy - interesting. Will try to remember that.

Comment: @mplungjan: yeah, proper syntax highlighting is a pet peeve of mine :)

Comment: @Andy: Then is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235153/nextsibiling-doesnt-work/6235174#6235174) acceptable?

Comment: @mplungjan: nice answer, but it would have been worth a +1 for the edit alone ;-)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To elaborate on the comments above:

#### You *cannot* write:

- `next("a")`, because [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) only tries to match the very next element. It will hit the `<br>` element and match nothing.
- `closest("a")` , because [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) walks up the ancestor chain, starting with the element itself, and therefore will miss the `<a>` elements.

#### You *can* write:

- `next().next()`, as Arend suggests. That's probably the fastest solution, but it makes the `<br>` elements mandatory.
- `nextAll("a")`, but that can return multiple elements (and will do so with your markup sample). Chaining into [first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) would prevent it, but [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) still would have to iterate over all the next siblings, which can make it slow depending on the complexity of the markup inside your `<div>` elements.
- `nextUntil("a").last().next()`, which only iterates over the next siblings until it finds a link, then returns the immediate next sibling of the last element matched. It *might* be faster than `nextAll()`, again, depending on your markup.

Comment: @mplungjan, indeed, but it also has the advantage of only matching a single `<a>` element, which you'll probably want given your markup structure :)

Comment: Interesting that jQuery does not mind me accessing the first in nextAll just by nextAll("a").attr("href") - seems it has a "do what I want, not what I say I want" ;) processor

Comment: @mplungjan, yes, jQuery is quite permissive in nature. Having the getter methods only fetch the value from the first matched element is a very good design decision in retrospect (the alternative being to return an array of values, one for each matched element, which can be achieved easily enough with `map()` anyway).

Comment: Did a really quick jsperf test to confirm performance on last two examples http://jsperf.com/js-sibling-select-test

Comment: `nextUntil("a").last().next()` would fail if the desired element is immediately after the starting element, because in such situation `nextUntil("a")` would return an empty collection, so in turn `.last()` then `.next()` would also return empty collections.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could just use the jQuery built-in function `.siblings()`

https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: That selects all matching siblings, not just the next matching one.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me

> $('#id ~ iframe');

Comment: Is this an answer to the question above?

Comment: Perhaps the adjacent `+` might be more relevant. In either case it would be a new access to the Dom from somewhere instead of relative to the checkbox. Your selector is not accessing the anchor next to the clicked checkbox