# Trouble Getting Next Anchor Object with Jquery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, anchor

(I'm sorry for the long post. I tend to be very thorough when explaining things.)

To start off with I want to say I'm new to Jquery, and I'm trying to teach myself by creating a custom image slider. I have the slider itself working with fade effects just fine with this code:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(
$(
    $(function(){
        $('.moonslide img:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){$('.moonslide img:first').fadeOut(3000).next('img').fadeIn(3000).end().appendTo('.moonslide');}, 6000);
    })
));
```

HTML

```
<div id="viewport">
  <div id="topslider">
    <div class="moonslide">

    <img src="/images/Slider/filer.jpg" class="slimage" id="ms0">
    <img src="/images/Slider/greenroom.jpg" class="slimage" id="ms1">
    <img src="/images/Slider/ng1.png" class="slimage" id="ms2">
    <img src="/images/Slider/ngs.png" class="slimage" id="ms3">                                                                        
    <img src="/images/Slider/worldworks.jpg" class="slimage" id="ms4">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="linkul" class="moonslidelinks">
    <a href="#" id="ml0">Slide 1</a><br />
    <a href="#" id="ml1">Slide 2</a><br />
    <a href="#" id="ml2">Slide 3</a><br />
    <a href="#" id="ml3">Slide 4</a> <br />
    <a href="#" id="ml4">Slide 5</a><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

The next thing I wanted to try was animating the navigation list with it. The first thing I set out to try was simply fading the link color from blue to white when the corresponding image is shown (I have already added the Jquery color plugin to animate css). I assumed that adding two effects to each motion would require me to break up the chain I have going for the fade effect. I started with simply making sure I could break this up correctly. So far I think I see how I need to break it up, however I'm having trouble getting the next anchor object after "a:first". I wrote the following code that works for the first and second image and the first anchor, but not for the second anchor.

```
$(document).ready($(
function(){

$('.moonslide img:gt(0)').hide();
$('.moonslidelinks a:first').css("color","#FFF");

$('.moonslide img:first').fadeOut(3000).next('img').fadeIn(3000);
$('.moonslidelinks a:first').animate({color: "#0083ff"}, 3000).next('a').animate({color: "#FFF"}, 3000);

}

));
```

When it didn't work I changed it to see if I was even getting to the next Anchor object:

```
$(document).ready($(
function(){

var nextImg = $('.moonslide img:first').next('img');
var nextA = $('.moonslidelinks a:first').next('a');
console.log(nextImg.attr('id'));
console.log(nextA.attr('id'));

}

));
```

This outputs the ID for the second image to the console just fine, but shows undefined for the anchor.

```
[00:02:11.080] "ms1"
[00:02:11.080] undefined
```

If I add a list to the navigation and try to get the next "li" ID, it works just fine.

```
$(document).ready($(
function(){

var nextImg = $('.moonslide img:first').next('img');
var nextA = $('.moonslidelinks li:first').next('li');
console.log(nextImg.attr('id'));
console.log(nextA.attr('id'));

}

));

<ul class="moonslidelinks">     
        <li id="li0"><a href="#" id="0">Slide 0</a></li>
        <li id="li1"><a href="#" id="1">Slide 1</a></li>
        <li id="li2"><a href="#" id="2">Slide 2</a></li>
        <li id="li3"><a href="#" id="3">Slide 3</a></li>
        <li id="li4"><a href="#" id="4">Slide 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Outputs:

```
[00:07:36.031] "ms1"
[00:07:36.031] "li1"
```

FINAL QUESTION (Once again, so sorry for the long post): Why is this not working for the anchor, but does work for LI and IMG? The "a:first" works just fine, but chaining a ".next" to it will not. Am I doing something wrong? Also, am I going down the right path for creating a slider with navigation effects, or am I sending myself down a rabbit hole anyway? Thank in advance to anybody that helps with this, and doesn't run away at the sight of my long post and over explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the "br" tags in between your anchor tags. The fastest solution would be:

```
$('.moonslidelinks a:first').animate({color: "#0083ff"}, 3000).next().next().animate({color: "#FFF"}, 3000);
```

Notice you need to call "next().next()" to get the "br", then the "a".

Review the selected answer here: [Cleanest way to get the next sibling in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237673/cleanest-way-to-get-a-sibling-in-jquery)

Comment: Is br considered a type of anchor?  Trying to understand why a <br /> would be selected by an "a:first" .next.

Comment: The "next" function only looks at the next **single** element. Since that element is a br, it will be undefined if you use .next('a'). Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. It would be nice if you could specify what type of element you are looking for next. Can I specify a class, then add a class to each of the anchors so it only looks for the next item that I want?

Comment: Agreed, it would be nice. :) If you look at the link at the end of my answer, the answer to that question has several other options. However, I think in your case .next().next() is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

The next element to anchor is `<br />` tag with no id. The `.next()` method returns only the element next to it whether you passed an argument to it or not.

```
<div id="linkul" class="moonslidelinks">
    <a href="#" id="ml0">Slide 1</a><br />
    ------------------------------- ------
                   |                  |
          Selects this first     The Next to it.
                   |                  |
        $('.moonslidelinks a:first').next('a')
                                         -----
                                           |
                                     It will not help
```

Comment: I see. I didn't know that. So there is no point in doing ".next('img')" or ".next('a')", right? Just simply do ".next()"?

Comment: @TomGordon have you looked at `.siblings()` method ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with so far. Both answers here were right in that specifying "next('a')" doesn't only look for anchors. Ryan Henderson's suggestion of using "next().next()" worked to get to the next anchor. I actually ended up scrapping the use of "next()" on the navigation side anyway though. As you can see by the code in my original post, I am rotating the images by taking the first image out and appending it to the end of the div. This way the code can simply grab the first image in the div each time it is run. I'm not sure if that's the best way or not, but like I said I am just trying to learn this (and that's what I came up with at the time). Because of this I don't have to worry about getting to the end of the list (with the images). When I got the code in place with "next().next()" I realized that it wasn't going to work, because I do have to worry about getting to the end of the navigation list. Using "next()" on the navigation side will get me to the end, then skip the first animation when it rolls back around. I ended up using the following, which may or may not be the best solution:

JS

```
$(document).ready($(
function(){

    $('.moonslide img:gt(0)').hide();
    $('.moonslidelinks a:first').css("color","#FFF");

    setInterval(function(){
        var curClass = $('.moonslide img:first').attr('id');
        var sp = curClass.split('ms');
        var curIndex = parseInt(sp[1]);
        var linkID = 'ml' + curIndex;
        if (curIndex < $('.moonslide').find('img').length-1) {var nextID = 'ml' + (curIndex+1);}
        else {var nextID = 'ml0';}

        $('.moonslide img:first').fadeOut(3000).next('img').fadeIn(3000).end().appendTo('.moonslide');   
        $("#"+linkID).animate({color: "#0083ff"}, 3000);
        $("#"+nextID).animate({color: "#FFF"}, 3000);

    }, 6000);

}

));
```

The next thing I would like to do to this script is put in some mouse over pauses. I'm not quite sure where to begin on that, but I will start digging into it tomorrow. My original question was answered by both replies above, so I would call this thread resolved (Thanks again to both of you!). Here is the full HTML page I am using for testing. This includes all of the CSS, HTML, and Javascript. I am always open to suggestions if you notice anything I could be doing better.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
a:link{color: #0083ff;}
a:active{color:#0083ff;}
a:visited{color:#0083ff;}
a:hover{color:#0083ff;}
.slimage {
    width: 650px;
    height: 410px;
}
.moonslide {
    position:relative;
    width: 650px;
    height: 410px;
}
.moonslide img{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -1000;
}
.moonslidelinks a{
    font-size: 1.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#viewport {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 800px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000;
}
#topslider {

    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    left: 37px;
    height: 420px;
    width: 950px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#MoonslideNav {
    top: 235px;
    left: 675px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 160px;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Jquery 1.10.2 //-->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.js"></script> <!-- Jquery Color Plugin //-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready($(
    function(){

        var fadeTime = 3000; // Time it takes to fade in and out in ms.
        var intTime = 6000; // Time before the next image effect starts in ms(counter starts as soon as fade in begins). 


        $('.moonslide img:gt(0)').hide();
        $('.moonslidelinks a:first').css("color","#FFF");
        setInterval(function(){
            var curID = $('.moonslide img:first').attr('id'); // Get first image (current image) ID
            var sp = curID.split('ms'); // Split first part of ID to leave only index number in sp[1]
            var curIndex = parseInt(sp[1]); // turn index number string into integer 
            var linkID = 'ml' + curIndex; // create string for current link ID
            if (curIndex < $('.moonslide').find('img').length-1) // Make sure current index is not the last image. 
            {var nextID = 'ml' + (curIndex+1);} // If it isn't, next index = current index + 1
            else {var nextID = 'ml0';} // If it is, next index = first link ID
            $('.moonslide img:first').fadeOut(fadeTime).next('img').fadeIn(fadeTime).end().appendTo('.moonslide');   // First Image Fade Out -> Next Image Fade In -> Move first Image to end
            $("#"+linkID).animate({color: "#0083ff"}, fadeTime); // Fade current navigation link out
            $("#"+nextID).animate({color: "#FFF"}, fadeTime); // Fade next navigation link in
        }, intTime); // Repeat after 6 seconds (includes the 3 seconds it takes to fade out / in). 
    }
));
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="viewport">
    <div id="topslider">
        <div class="moonslide">
            <img src="/images/Slider/filer.jpg" class="slimage" id="ms0">
            <img src="/images/Slider/greenroom.jpg" class="slimage" id="ms1">
            <img src="/images/Slider/ng1.png" class="slimage" id="ms2">
            <img src="/images/Slider/ngs.png" class="slimage" id="ms3">                                                                        
            <img src="/images/Slider/worldworks.jpg" class="slimage" id="ms4">
        </div>
        <div id="MoonslideNav" class="moonslidelinks">
            <a href="#" id="ml0">Slide 1</a><br />
            <a href="#" id="ml1">Slide 2</a><br />
            <a href="#" id="ml2">Slide 3</a><br />
            <a href="#" id="ml3">Slide 4</a><br />
            <a href="#" id="ml4">Slide 5</a><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```