# How do I select the first sibling of a certain element type with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

The HTML is structured like this:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<img src="" />
<p></p> // I want to select this element 
<h1></h1>
<p></p>
<h2></h2>
```

Based on my start element `<div id="myDiv">` There are several more `<p>` siblings but I only want the first one, as seen in the code.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Closely related to [Cleanest way to get a sibling in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237673/cleanest-way-to-get-a-sibling-in-jquery) (with an `<img>` element instead of a `<br>`, but the same principle stands).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
jQuery('#myDiv').siblings('p:first')
```

or

```
jQuery('#myDiv').siblings('p').first()
```

would do the trick

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#myDiv ~ p').first()
```

or pure css selector(not checked the performance, but it could be the fastest solution,as it uses [.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)):

```
jQuery('#myDiv ~ p:first-of-type')
```

Answer (score -1):

As Olivier suggests .first() or p:first would suit your needs, though a more general solution would be to us .eq(n) - where n is the number you want starting from 0.

For instance, to select the first sibling paragraph of #myDiv you would use:

```
    jQuery('#myDiv').siblings('p').eq(0);
```

To target the third paragraph, all you would do is change the number. Remember that as it starts from 0 you effectively need to take one away from the desired target:

```
    jQuery('#myDiv').siblings('p').eq(2);
```

Comment: In question `p` is not a child of `#myDiv`. This CSS selector `#myDiv p` will select only the `p` inside `#myDiv`