# How can i select a specific element after i've clicked another element in the same div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a h3 element and a p element which are inside a div element ,like this:

```
<div class="question">
    <h3> <a href="#"> *a question* <img class="arrow" src="" alt="an-arrow-img"> </img> </a> </h3>
    <p> *an answer* </p>
</div>
```

And I have a class named "show" in my css file, which looks like this:

```
//shows the answer when I click the h3 element
.show{
   display: block;
}
```

on the website, I'm trying to make the questions-answers look like this:

show-hide p element

[image]

I've used javascript to toggle the class "show" when I click the questions (h3 elements) but I toggle them all and can't figure out how i can select the one I've clicked. My javascript code is this one till now:

```
$("h3").on("click", function(){
   $("p").toggleClass("show");
});
```

Is it my HTML structure that's wrong, or is there a way to combine the $(this) selector to show the answer only to the question I've clicked?

Comment: This: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cleanest way to get the next sibling in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237673/cleanest-way-to-get-the-next-sibling-in-jquery) Read:  https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/next

Comment: thank you very much for your answers, the next() method worked properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JQuery.next() to select sibling of $this.

```js
$("h3").on("click", function(){
   $(this).next("p").toggleClass("show");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var question = document.getElementsByClassName("question");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
  question[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var answer = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (answer.style.maxHeight) {
      answer.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      answer.style.maxHeight = answer.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.question {
  background-color: #2d6596;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .question:hover {
  background-color: #1a364f;
}

.question:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.answer {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="question">The question</button>
<div class="answer">
  <p>The answer</p>
</div>

<button class="question">The question</button>
<div class="answer">
  <p>The answer</p>
</div>

<button class="question">The question</button>
<div class="answer">
  <p>The answer</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice and clear!